# Selenium Python - Explicit waits not working

Tags: python, selenium, time, web-scraping

I am unable to get explicit waits to work while waiting for the page to render the js, so I am forced to use time.sleep() in order for the code to work as intended.

I read the docs and still wasn't able to get it to work.
http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

The commented out section of code with the time.sleep() works as intended.
The WebDriverWait part runs but does not wait.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url = "https://www.target.com/"

# tells the driver to wait up to 10 seconds before timing out
# for data that will be loaded on the screen
DELAY = 10
driver.implicitly_wait(DELAY)
SLEEP_TIME = 1

# navigate to the page
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(SLEEP_TIME)

try:

    WebDriverWait(driver, DELAY).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, """//*[@id="js-toggleLeftNav"]/img"""))).click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, DELAY).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, """//*[@id="5"]"""))).click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, DELAY).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#leftNavigation > ul:nth-child(2)")))
    """
    # opens up the side bar javascript
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="js-toggleLeftNav"]/img""").click()
    time.sleep(SLEEP_TIME)

    # clicks on browse by category
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="5"]""").click()
    time.sleep(SLEEP_TIME)

    # gets all the category elements
    items = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#leftNavigation > ul:nth-child(2)").find_elements_by_tag_name("li")
    time.sleep(SLEEP_TIME)
    """
    # gets the hyperlink and category name but the first and the last,
    # since the first is back to main menu and the last is exit
    category_links = {}
    for i in range(1, len(items) - 1):
        hyperlink = items[i].find_element_by_tag_name('a').get_attribute('href')
        category_name = items[i].text
        category_links[category_name] = hyperlink

    print(category_links)

except:
    print("Timed out.")
```

Comment: I wrote a framework for selenium in python that takes care of tedious tasks like these, the official bindings are a bit funky in that they feel a bit dated in terms of workflow with larger sites/apps. If you wanted to check it out you can view it https://github.com/neetjn/py-component-controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This version successfully loads the site, waits for it to render, then opens the side menu.  Notice how the **wait.until** method is is used successfully wait until the page is loaded.  You should be able to use the pattern below with the rest of your code to achieve your goal.

**CODE**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get("https://www.target.com/")

wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#leftNavigation > ul:nth-child(2)")))
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="js-toggleLeftNavLg"]""")
button.click()
time.sleep(5)


driver.quit()
```

Comment: Still getting the element not visible error when it ran button.click()
"selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible"

Comment: @JonathanIshii Double check the xpath id's, you may be getting a different version of the page than me.

Comment: Ahh I got it. I needed to recall **wait.until** everytime I called **click()** because the js reloaded the page. Thank you so much!