# Selenium cannot continue after field is filled out

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Below code clicks a field, fills it out with Hyundai, and presses enter, which should close the dropdown menu. But it never does, therefore it does not continue to fill out next field.

So far I tried telling it to click anywhere in order to close dropdown - didn't work.
Tried adding .submit() and .click() after send_keys() - didn't work.

Desired result: Let me fill out next field.

Edit: I noticed the ID of the field I want to choose changes everytime I reload. Is there a way around this?

Here's where it is stuck:

[image: stuck image]

Second comment: I typed in multiple Keys.TAB, but it doesn't respond to it. I am not sure how to solve this mystery..

```
.send_keys("Hyundai", Keys.ENTER, Keys.TAB, Keys.ENTER, Keys.TAB, Keys.TAB, Keys.TAB)
```

```
#imports
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

#options
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
#chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")

# enable browser logging
d = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
d['loggingPrefs'] = { 'browser':'ALL' }
driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities = d, options=chrome_options)
driver.fullscreen_window()

driver.get("https://forsikringsguiden.dk/#!/bilforsikring/manuel")  #URL

#Fills out field called "Mærke" with Hyundai      
marke = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="s2id_carSelectedMake"]/a').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="s2id_autogen1_search"]').send_keys("Hyundai", Keys.ENTER)

#next field to fill out
model = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="s2id_autogen2"]').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="s2id_autogen3_search"]').send_keys("i30", Keys.ENTER)
```

Update: I believe the reason it gets stuck in the first field is because of the "overlay" - id=select2-drop-mask I added these javescript lines:

```
js = "var aa=document.getElementsByClassName('select2-drop-mask')[0];aa.parentNode.removeChild(aa)"
driver.execute_script(js)
```

It seems like work, but now it keeps on jumping down between field 1 and 2.

Comment: Alternatively I could also try to choose from the drop-down instead of using the search function. Will report back if it works.

Comment: Why don't you use Protractor? You are dealing with Angular based application.

Comment: Will look it up! Haven't heard of it before tbh

Comment: @Moro how do you suggest I use it?

Comment: Switch to javascript and use Protractor instead of Selenium ;) The hard way

Comment: LOL, don't know javascript, only python. Thanks though

Answer (score 0):

It is happening due to focus of element is not achieved.

You need to scroll down till the element is appear on page.

Add below python code in your script :

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element);
```

OR

```
driver.execute_script("scrollBy(0,250);")
```

Below java code working for me:

```
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://forsikringsguiden.dk/#!/bilforsikring/manuel");

    Thread.sleep(5000);

    WebElement e1= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='s2id_carSelectedMake']/a"));

    JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    jse.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", e1);

    e1.click();

    Thread.sleep(2000);

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='s2id_autogen1_search']")).sendKeys("Hyundai", Keys.ENTER);

    jse.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", e1);

    WebElement e2= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='s2id_autogen2']"));

    jse.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", e2);

    e2.click();

    Thread.sleep(2000);

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='s2id_autogen3_search']")).sendKeys("i30", Keys.ENTER);
```

Comment: I add in the scrolls, but it doesn't change anything. Still doesn't move away from the first field. Perhaps I should as well implement the sleeps? time.sleep() in python

Comment: thread I have put for my simplicity .. you need to add waits like explicit wait , while python have sleep time.sleep(2.4)

Comment: Its not recommnaded to use sleep use exclipcit wait and you have missed the implicit wait as well

Comment: driver.implicitly_wait(60)

Comment: add this after get method

Comment: Implemented bu cursor still doesn't move away from first field. Manually you can type search and if it matches an item in dropdown list you can press enter and it fills out field, and you can click on next field (just like any other search button/dropdown list). But selenium doesn't seem to get this.

Comment: its working for me so selenium does handle it, its due to mismagment of waits. I also observe its due to screen resolution

Comment: you can also do scroll using   driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)

Comment: I have "driver.fullscreen_window()"

Comment: screen resolution differ monitor to monitor.. forget that .. I have added a new javascript and upated the code .. please try with it

Comment: also see how to add exclipt wait -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48313021/selenium-python-explicit-waits-not-working

Comment: Here's where it gets stuck: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4J51T.png

Comment: It is not the scrolling that's the issue. I cannot make selenium move away form the first field, even though it successfully get's filled out. It simply doesn't move the dropdown menu. waiting and scrolling unfortunately didn't help me.

Comment: ok .. try one thing ... put enter in another statment like :  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='s2id_autogen1_search']")).sendKeys("Hyundai");
  
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='s2id_autogen1_search']")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);

Comment: Also try to put wait between them if still not work

Comment: for me its not working if it do not use scroll .. so better if you put it and do as I suggest in last comments

Comment: I tried, both wait and scrolling. Still seems to be stuck in type mode. I even implemented .send_keys("Hyundai", Keys.ARROW_DOWN, Keys.ENTER). Still didn't work :(

Comment: have you tried to put them in different statement as I told .. my previous comment ->put enter in another statment like : driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='s2id_autogen1_search']")).sendKeys("Hyundai"); driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='s2id_autogen1_search']")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);

Comment: I added this to my code. It's supposedly to remove an element from HTML: js = "var aa=document.getElementsByClassName('select2-drop-mask')[0];aa.parentNode.removeChild(aa)"
driver.execute_script(js)

Comment: I do not think its required ... in your posted code I am still not able to see kind of waits ... neither implict, explicit and nether thread

Comment: I have figured out the culprit. And it has nothing to do with the Wait's, Threads etc. When a field is filled out, this overlay pops up: "id=select2-drop-mask". That's why selenium cannot continue, because everything else is in the background now. How to bypass select2-drop-mask?

Answer (score 0):

To select Car model you need to capture the `Select` html element, like this:

```
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#carSelectedMake"))
```

then select the option of your choice by visible text:

```
select.select_by_visible_text("Kia")
```

Other fields will work in the same manner, I have managed to interact with model selector via: `ng-model='carSelectedModel'`